# How can I get my search bar to float right

Tags: html, css

I am doing an individual project, and in it, I want to put the search bar to the right, but for some reason I can't seem to get it to got to the right.

Here is the css codes that I use:

```css
.searchbox {
  /*width: 210px; 
       border: 5px solid #f8c7f2;
       background-color: #66cc00;
       margin-bottom: 30px;*/
  float: right;
}

.right_section_content {
  width: 180px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.right_section_content form {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.right_section_content input {
  width: 180px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.right_section_content .button {
  width: 70px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Searchbox">
  <h4>Search</h4>
  <div class="right_section_content">
    <form method="get" action="#">
      <input name="keyword" type="text" id="keyword" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" value="Search" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML to go with this CSS, please? It will help to see exactly what you're going for.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: use position instead of float

Answer (score 0):

You almost have it. HTML class names are [case sensitive](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#attribute-case). You need to change `Searchbox` to match the CSS selector: `.searchbox`, or vice versa:

```css
.searchbox {
  width: 210px;   
  border: 5px solid #f8c7f2;
  background-color: #66cc00;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  float: right;
}

.right_section_content {
  width: 180px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.right_section_content form {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.right_section_content input {
  width: 180px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.right_section_content .button {
  width: 70px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
```

```html
<div class="searchbox">
  <h4>Search</h4>
  <div class="right_section_content">
    <form method="get" action="#">
      <input name="keyword" type="text" id="keyword" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" value="Search" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, if you *really* need to use `Searchbox` you can use a case-insensitive attribute selector by appending the attribute with an `i`, but this potentially can negatively impact performance:

```css
[class~="searchbox" i] {
  width: 210px;   
  border: 5px solid #f8c7f2;
  background-color: #66cc00;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  float: right;
}

.right_section_content {
  width: 180px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.right_section_content form {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.right_section_content input {
  width: 180px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.right_section_content .button {
  width: 70px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
```

```html
<div class="Searchbox">
  <h4>Search</h4>
  <div class="right_section_content">
    <form method="get" action="#">
      <input name="keyword" type="text" id="keyword" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" value="Search" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use position instead of float

Comment: Why? @Kashirhasnain there’s no right or wrong way in this circumstance. I was going off what the OP has. Float is not deprecated and still very useful. Additionally that’s not even the problem, the OP didn’t have proper casing for the class name as noted in the answer